# In Contravariance, what does it mean for a reference's assignment compatibility to be reversed?

Tags: c#, .net, contravariance

In Contravariance, what does it mean for a *reference's assignment compatibility to be reversed*?

> **Covariance and Contravariance (C#)**
>
> ```
> // Assignment compatibility.   
> string str = "test";  
> // An object of a more derived type is assigned to an object of a less derived type.   
> object obj = str;  
>
> // Covariance.   
> IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>();  
> // An object that is instantiated with a more derived type argument   
> // is assigned to an object instantiated with a less derived type argument.   
> // Assignment compatibility is preserved.   
> IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;  
>
> // Contravariance.             
> // Assume that the following method is in the class:   
> // static void SetObject(object o) { }   
> Action<object> actObject = SetObject;  
> // An object that is instantiated with a less derived type argument   
> // is assigned to an object instantiated with a more derived type argument.   
> // Assignment compatibility is reversed.   
> Action<string> actString = actObject;
> ```

**ref:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Moreover, when attempting to cast from a less-derived type to a more-derived one, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown.  Since *user-defined conversions aren't allowed to or from a base class*, I don't see how contravariance of method groups even work - wouldn't/shouldn't invoking such a method throw an `InvalidCastException` as well?

---

Update: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/30/whats-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility/

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. You're asking/acting as if *allowing contravariance* was something that had to be implemented *within the rules of the C# language*, which of course is not the case. The rules of the language were *changed* to allow contravariance to occur.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've read a few articles on how it's introduction was potentially code-breaking (https://csharp.2000things.com/tag/assignment-compatibility/ 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/ 
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

Comment: Contravariance is the observation that if an argument is supposed to be an `object`, then surely it's also allowed to be a `string` (which is an `object`), and delegates ought to accommodate that, therefore every `Action<object>` can be treated as an `Action<string>`, since the `Action` would ask no more of the `string` than it would ask of any old `object`. The conversion involved is the trivial one from `string` to `object`, not the other way around, and no user-defined conversions are involved.

Comment: `(object < string) => (Action<string> < Action<object>)(in T)`, since `Action<object>` is assignment compatible (representation preserving), in argument `T`, with (can be stored into) `Action<string>`. Therefore, `Action<T>` is contravariant over T.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Assignment compatibility is reversed* means that you can assign a less derived type to a more derived type.

In the example the contravariance is shown with the `Action` class. `Action<object>` can be assigned to `Action<string>`.

This code is valid:

```
public void Test(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.GetType().ToString());
}

Action<string> foo;
foo = Test;
foo.Invoke("bar");
```

In this example we can see that the string *"bar"* is implicitly cast to the object type when it's passed as a parameter to the `Test` method. There is no invalid cast or user-defined conversion involved.

`Action` is not covariant, so `Action<string>` can't be assigned to `Action<object>`, trying to do so would throw an exception.

Generic types are contravariant when the generic type is an input parameter and covariant with output parameters.
So the `Func` class is covariant with it's first type and contravariant with it's second (and third, ...):

- `Func<string, object>` can be assigned to `Func<string, string>`
- `Func<string, string>` can be assigned to `Func<object, string>`
- `Func<string, object>` can be assigned to `Func<object, string>`
- `Func<object, string>` can't be assigned to `Func<string, string>`.

To declare a contravariant generic type in C# we can declare a contravariant interface with the `in` keyword. In doing so we are restricted to use the generic type as an input parameter:

```
interface IMyGenericType<in T>
{
    object Test(T input); //allowed
    //T GetValue(); //not allowed in a contravariant interface
}
```

With this type I can assign `IMyGenericType<object>` to `IMyGenericType<string>`.

Comment: For the second part of my question then, I have things reversed... By your first example, if `Test` took a `string` and was instead covariantly invoked with `((Action<object>)Test).Invoke(new object())`, then wouldn't a cast exception be thrown?

Comment: @sαmosΛris: LINQPad is your friend for quickly testing things like this. `Action<string> Test = s => Console.WriteLine(s); ((Action<object>)Test).Invoke(new object());` -> ``Unable to cast object of type 'System.Action`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Action`1[System.Object]``.

Comment: @JeroenMostert But is that not the same type of covariance used in the example of the op (`IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string>(); IEnumerable<object> objects = strings;)?`

Comment: @sαmosΛris IEnumerable is covariant while Action is contravariant, and with contravariance assignment compatibility is reversed.

Comment: @sαmosΛris: compare `Func<string> Test = () => ""; ((Func<object>)Test).Invoke();` -- no error. Parameters are contravariant, return values are covariant, hence `in` and `out` on interface specifications. It's all about how the interface uses the types.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Action https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx reference, which says,that T argument is passed with in,which means it's contravariant.

```
 static object GetObject() { return null; }  
 static void SetObject(object obj) { }  

static string GetString() { return ""; }  
static void SetString(string str) { }  

static void Test()  
{  
    // Covariance. A delegate specifies a return type as object,  
    // but you can assign a method that returns a string.  
    Func<object> del = GetString;  

    // Contravariance. A delegate specifies a parameter type as string,  
    // but you can assign a method that takes an object.  
    Action<string> del2 = SetObject;  
}
```

In this example,contravariance is obvious and it works,because any string  that you will pass to del2,can become object.So contravariance should be implemented in places where it's logical to implement contravariant solution,like the Action delegate type argument,another example is IComparer interface.